# discord.py "wait_for" a reaction in a command

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command which sends an embed to a specific channel. The bot then adds a reaction to this message. That works so far.

Now, when someone clicks on this reaction, I want the bot to respond with a message. But that doesn't work. There is no error, which means that it works in some way, but not like I want.

```
@bot.command()
async def buy(ctx, choice):
    # some code ...

    mess1 = await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await mess1.add_reaction('<a:check:674039577882918931>')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return reaction.message == mess1 and str(reaction.emoji) == '<a:check:674039577882918931>'

    await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
    channeldone = bot.get_channel(705836078082424914)
    await channeldone.send('test')
```

Comment: Is there an error message in the output?

Comment: No, there isn't an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though your `reaction.message == mess1` condition is returning `False`, and I can't narrow it down as to why that's happening, but I'll edit this if I do.

A way to overcome this would be to evaluate the IDs of the messages:

```py
return reaction.message.id == mess1.id and str(reaction.emoji) == '<a:check:674039577882918931>'
```

And this will evaluate to `True` when the bot reacts, so I'd recommend adding another condition to check that the user reacted, if that is what you want the user to do:

```py
return .... and user == ctx.author
```

---

**References:**

- [`Message.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.id)
- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)