# I'm trying to learn discord py for the most part, and I can't seem to get a valid response from reactions

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a rock paper scissors command on discord, but my bot does not respond to a person's reactions.

The `rpsai` variable is for my rock paper scissors 'AI' which determines rock, paper or scissors randomly.

```
from random import randint
rpsai = randint(1,3)
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction == "":
        if rpsai==1: 
           await message.channel.send('I pick Rock, we tie!')
        if rpsai==2:
           await message.channel.send('I pick Paper, I win!')
        if rpsai==3:
           await message.chanel.send('I pick Scissors, I lose')
```

Comment: Do you have all your imports? Is you client/ bot defined? Are you using commands or a message event? Please include this in your question, because this question feels incomplete.

Comment: there is so much added code to this with different features and i didn't want to include the entirety of it, a lot of it is a mess, I have discord and random imported.

Comment: Is this code under a command, like `@client.command` or `@bot.command`?

Comment: probably woulda been easier to set it up under commands, but it is just waiting until it hears !rps

Comment: Where is your bot waiting for !rps then? `on_reaction_add` is an event (`client.event`, `bot.event`, etc.). The code you provided would work as in: `Receive reaction from ANY message` -> `If reaction is ` -> `Send message`. You would want to put this into a command and use [a check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65082883/discord-py-detecting-reactions)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some *issues* with the code you provided:

1. [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add) is an event function. This is not recommended for what you're trying to do, and it would be preferable if you used the `.command()` instead.
2. You need to use [`wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) if you're using a command. Your bot isn't going to be listening for a reaction until you tell it to via `wait_for()`.

Here is some code that may help fix these problems:

```py
@client.command() # or @bot.command() depending on what you're using
async def rps(ctx): # you mentioned 'AI', so you won't need any arguments
    msg = await ctx.send("✂...")

    # adding reactions
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    await msg.add_reaction("✂")

    bot_choice = random.randint(1, 3) # picking a random number from 1 to 3
    
    # this is the check and wait_for
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction) in ["", "", "✂"] and reaction.message == msg

    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check) # or bot.wait_for
    
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
        if bot_choice == 1: # Rock
            await ctx.send('I pick Rock, we tie!')
        if bot_choice == 2: # Paper
            await ctx.send('I pick Paper, I win!')
        if bot_choice == 3: # Scissors
           await ctx.send('I pick Scissors, I lose')
    # Then you do the same thing for the others. Don't forget to add this when including Paper and Scissors!
```

Here is this exact code working below. I renamed it `test` since I already have a `rps` command, but you get the point.

[image: Working Code rps]

**Other References**:

- [SO: Discord.py-rewrite wait_for() how do i use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571844/discord-py-rewrite-wait-for-how-do-i-use)
- [SO: discord.py “wait_for” a reaction in a command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62374650/14420546)
- [SO: How to loop with a reaction embed menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675404/how-to-loop-with-a-reaction-embed-menu) (Does include examples of `wait_for()`)